# Exactly 50% of 2-adic integers have the norm equal to $1$, exactly 25% have the norm $\frac{1}{2}$ and so on?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

The question itself is more general and relates to all p-adic numbers, but it's really easy to show the principle using 2-adics.

The definition of p-adic norm in most textbooks is not easy to understand, but here it is the way I understand it:

*The norm of a p-adic number equals $\frac{1}{p^{n-1}}$ with $n$ being the index (the position) of the rightmost non-zero digit we can find.*

So, let's start listing all possible 2-adic numbers written with certain precision:

$$
\begin{matrix}
& &...0~~& &  & &~~...1 & & \\ 
&...00 &  &...10 &  & ...01 &  & ...11 &\\ 
...000  & ...100  & ...010  & ...110 &  & ...001 & ...101  & ...011  & ...111 \\ 
\end{matrix}
$$

It can be continued indefinitely. It is easy to see from this pattern that *exactly* half of 2-adic integers are units, i.e. their norm is $1$, exactly 25% have the norm $\frac{1}{2}$ and so on.

And even more general conclusion can be made using the definition of the distance on 2-adic set - for any given 2-adic integer the distance from it to 50% of other numbers is $1$, to 25% is $\frac{1}{2}$ and so on.

I undertand that it's not a proof, but is there some truth here? Is it correct to say that $\frac{1}{2}$ of 2-adics, $\frac{2}{3}$ of 3-adics, $\frac{4}{5}$ of 5-adics and so on all have the norm $1$?

Comment: You need measure theory to make sense of what it means for 50% of an infinite set to have a property. Are half of the integers even? Until you can define what that question means, it is just random words put together. That said, the $p$-adic integers have a natural probability measure which has the property you want.

Comment: I undertand, but we can't exactly know about even/odd integers, because for numbers approaching infinity there is no possible way to tell if they are even or odd. P-adic norm is completely different from this case - we always can tell if p-adic number is a unit or not

Comment: We can always tell if an integer is even or odd. No idea what you mean. Integers are, after all, a subset of $p$-adic numbers, so if we can tell if a $2$-adic ends with $0$ or $1$, we can tell whether an integer is even or odd. The real problem on the integers is related to measure theory - Ther is no good measure on the integers.

Comment: But for integers we could just use the Schnirelmann density, couldn't we?

Comment: You can use density, as long as you are careful not to treat density as a probability. @LeonAragones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to do this from group theory. First consider the subgroup $p\Bbb Z_p$ of $\Bbb Z_p$. The cosets are the sets $n+p\Bbb Z_p$, for $0\le n<p$. All the elements $a\in n+p\Bbb Z_p$, for $n\ne0$, have $p$-norm equal to $1$. Since the elements of one coset can be put into very natural one-one correspondence with the elements of another, it’s fair to say that $(p-1)/p$ of the elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ have $p$-norm $1$. Now just multiply what I’ve said, and the supporting argument, by $p$: $(p-1)/p$ of the elements of $p\Bbb Z_p$ have $p$-norm $1/p$, right? And so on.